# Java Programming My Data cannot show when I click the Row

Tags: java, sql

Hi friends I've been difficult to get my row in SQL. When I use mouse event in Java just 4 field in my row data appear.

```
private void jtb_dataasetMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                          
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    // Mouse Pilih
    int bar = jtb_dataaset.getSelectedRow();
    String a = jtb_dataaset.getValueAt(bar, 0).toString();
    jid_aset1.setText(a);
    String b = tabmode.getValueAt(bar, 1).toString();
    jnm_aset.setText(b);
    String c = tabmode.getValueAt(bar, 2).toString();
    jmrk.setText(c);
    String d = tabmode.getValueAt(bar, 3).toString();
    jsernum.setText(d);
    String e = tabmode.getValueAt(bar, 5).toString();
    jkondisi.setSelectedItem(e);
}
```

[This is look like when I choose the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ynf97.png)

I still difficult, please correct me if I made a mistake. I use the enum string in string.

Comment: so whats your question?

Comment: Sorry, my question is I wonder why my combo box not appear in my data. And it seems that I made a mistake. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From the *javadoc* for method [setSelectedItem(Object anObject)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#setSelectedItem(java.lang.Object))

> If anObject is not in the list and the combo box is uneditable, it will not change the current selection

Looks like the value in your `JTable` does not match a value in your `JComboBox`.

I suggest printing out the `JTable` value.
After this line of the code you posted...

```java
String e = tabmode.getValueAt(bar, 5).toString();
```

add this line...

```java
System.out.println("^" + e + "^");
```

Then compare that with the value that you think should be matched in your `JComboBox`.

A good programmer **must** know how to debug code. Have you read this Web page?

[How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

And regarding posting questions, in general, I recommend that you read this Web page.

[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thanks for your help and other refrences. It look like I made a mistake to assign number at bar. Many Thanks